# How to use BCryptPasswordEncoder on account registration and on account authentication in spring?

Tags: authentication, spring-security, spring-boot

I have created a web application based on Spring-Boot 1.2.2.RELEASE. I also have a database table where I manage user credentials. It has the basic columns e.g. id, username, and password. Also added salt column where I plan to store randomly generated salts per account.

I'm trying to use Spring Security and having some difficulty with authentication using the encoded password. So basically I have a Register Controller:

```
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<User> register(@RequestParam(value = "email_address") String emailAddress, @RequestParam(value = "password") String password) {
    String username = emailAddress;
    String salt = KeyGenerators.string().generateKey(); 
    User user = new User();
    user.setUsername(emailAddress);
    user.setEmailAddress(emailAddress);
    user.setSalt(salt);
    user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(username+salt+password));
    user.setCreatedBy(1);
    user.setCreatedOn(new Date());
    user.setLastUpdatedby(1);
    user.setLastUpdatedOn(new Date());
    user.setStartDate(new Date());
    return new ResponseEntity<User>(this.userRepository.save(user), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Then I implemented UserDetailsService like this:

```
@Service
protected static class ApplicationUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = this.userRepository.findByUsername(username);

        if (user == null) {
            return null;
        }

        List<GrantedAuthority> auth = AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList("ROLE_USER");

        String password = passwordEncoder.encode(username+user.getSalt()+user.getPassword());

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(username, password, auth);
    }
}
```

However, since BCryptPasswordEncoder generates new result everytime even if the input is the same, how will it be able to authenticate?

**EDIT:**
Just wanted to add that if I don't use any encoder and store the password as plain text, I am able to authenticate just fine. But of course that's not what I want to do.

**UPDATE 1**
Here's config for WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. Inside it I have the configure method.

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
protected static class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  private ApplicationUserDetailsService applicationUserDetailsService;

  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)   throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(applicationUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
  }

  @Bean 
  @Override
  protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManager();
  }

}
```

**UPDATE 2**
I got it working by extending DaoAuthenticationProvider. See updated code below.

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
protected static class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationUserDetailsService applicationUserDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(applicationUserDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean   
    @Override
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManager();
    }

}
```

Also had to modify my RegisterController as shown below.

```
@RestController
public class RegisterController {

  @Autowired
  private UserRepository userRepository;

  private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

  @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public ResponseEntity<User> register(@RequestParam(value = "email_address") String emailAddress, @RequestParam(value = "password") String password) {
    User user = new User();
    user.setUsername(emailAddress);
    user.setEmailAddress(emailAddress);
    user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(password));
    user.setSalt(KeyGenerators.string().generateKey());
    user.setCreatedBy(1);
    user.setCreatedOn(new Date());
    user.setLastUpdatedby(1);
    user.setLastUpdatedOn(new Date());
    user.setStartDate(new Date());
    return new ResponseEntity<User>(this.userRepository.save(user), HttpStatus.OK);
  }

}
```

**UPDATE 3**

Forgot to include the updated UserDetailService implementation.

```
@Service
protected static class ApplicationUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = this.userRepository.findByUsername(username);

        if (user == null) {
            return null;
        }

        List<GrantedAuthority> auth = AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList("ROLE_USER");

        String password = passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword());

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(username, password, auth);
    }
}
```

I might need to remove the salt column now since it's basically useless.

Hopefully this helps others as well.

Comment: Have you configured Authentication Manager Builder? 
In case if you are using latest spring security then please refer below posts to setup Jdbc Authentication.
http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.0.RC2/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-authentication-jdbc
Sample
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/master/samples/jdbc-jc

Comment: Yes. Please see the updated code above. Also I checked this [code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/samples/jdbc-jc/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/samples/config/SecurityConfig.java) from the link you provided, I don't understand how it will map the username/password passed during authentication to my custom users table. Is this done by default?

Comment: Basically in standard implementation DaoAuthenticationProvider will handle that for you if you are using custome tables then you will need to build your own custom versions of JdbcUserDetailsManagerConfigurer and JdbcUserDetailsManager and plug those in AuthenticationManagerBuilder to have it in the java config way of spring security, As per my view xml based approach might be better option if you want to use custom tables or user details, It will required less efforts to customize it as per your needs.

Comment: Thanks. I made some changes and extended DaoAuthenticationProvider. Somehow I got it to work. Updated my post above with the latest and working codes. Off-topic: BTW, is xml config allowed in spring-boot. I'm new to spring and when I created a new Spring project in STS, it did not create any xml file.

Comment: Yes, you can use @ImportResource to get configurations from xml files